# Remove the n last elements from a list . I get error: "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list"

Tags: python, list

I have an error in this code and I don't get why is it wrong.

```
LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]
print(x[-4:])
def remove_last_elements(the_list):
    while len(the_list) > 5 in the_list:
       the_list.remove(the_list[-4:])
    print(the_list)
remove_last_elements(LL)
```

The output should be LL=[2,3,4,5]. I need that len()>5, because I have several lists ( nested) with different amount of elements.

Here the error message I have got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/APPL/DPI/PDF_reader/test_general.py", line 68, in <module>
    remove_last_elements(LL)
  File "C:/APPL/DPI/PDF_reader/test_general.py", line 66, in remove_last_elements
    the_list.remove(the_list[-4:])
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: `len(the_list) > 5 in the_list` checks if a boolean value `len(the_list) > 5` is present in the list. Is that what you wanted to write?

Comment: @ForceBru: It's actually comparison chaining, not checking if a boolean is in the list, but it's wrong either way (as is the next line).

Comment: I want to remove the last n items if the length of the list is greater than 5. should I use an if structure?

Comment: @user2357112, so, is it checking if `len(the_list) > (5 in the_list)` then? I'm not sure about this, since `a=[4]; len(a) >= 4 in a` is `False`, as it should be, but `a=[4]; len(a) >= (4 in a)` (that is, ` len(a) >= True`) is `True`

Comment: In other words, you want to ensure that the list has no more than 5 items?

Comment: @ForceBru It is checking if `(len(the_list) > 5) and (5 in the_list)`.

Comment: @DYZ, now that's weird. Apparently, [`in` is a comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), didn't really expect that

Comment: @DYZ yes, I want to check if the list has no more than 5 items. if it has, I want to remove elements so the list will have no more than 5.

Comment: Abumaru: you reference your list with three different variable names: `LL`, `x`, `the_list`; but you didn't even define the last two, so your code won't even run for us. Please tidy up your code example and test it runs in a clean shell, then edit your question to fix that. Welcome to SO, but questions here are required to have a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use a simple comparison for this.  If the list has more than 5 elements, drop the final 5.  Think of it as keeping all *but* the final 5.

```
if len(the_list) > 5:
    the_list = the_list[:-4]
```

If you want to reduce the list until you have no more than 5 elements, then replace the `if` with a `while`.

---

*update per OP clarification*

Your task is to remove groups of 5 elements until there are no more than 5.  This is simple enough with the modulus operator.

```
final_size = len(the_list) % 5
if final_size = 0:
    final_size = 5

the_list = the_list[:final_size]
```

---

Your original code has several structural problems.  If you're worried about how many elements are in the list, why are you checking for a particular element?  `5 in the_list` is looking for the *value* 5, rather than 5 elements.

Second, your list is composed of integers, but you're trying to remove a self-referential sublist:

```
the_list.remove(the_list[-4:])
```

As you already know, that slice is a specific list of five elements.  You do not have a sub-list in `the_list`, so you won't find that as an element.  If you want to specifically remove each of the elements from the original list, you'll have to iterate through them in turn.  It's much easier simply to grab the list slice that you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to check any conditions. Just *attempt* to take the first five elements:

```
the_list = the_list[:5]
```

If there are fewer than five elements in the list, the slicing operator will be ignored.